time clause with when
As I understand in time clauses present simple or past simple can mean either during or after some event. Perfect means only after. I was told that with verbs that indicate short actions such as throw or finish there is no real difference between simple and perfect both indicate after those activities. On the other hand with verbs that show long action such as play or work the difference is big because with these verbs present simple means either during of after the activity whereas perfect means only after.

When I work she comes

When I work she sleeps


So, according to my knowledge both 1 and 2 can have a double meaning for 1 either when I am working or have worked she comes and for 2 either when i am working she is sleeping or when I have worked she sleeps. Is my understanding correct?
Ps I know my previus question is similar but here I provide my understading

Both sentences have many possible meanings. Only an exact full context tells us which specific meaning applies. Note that some (not all) of the meanings can be equally expressed using while (or whilst) instead of when.

You need a spellchecker, there are  two spelling mistakes in the P.S note. Old habits die hard…

Although you might imagine that any combination of words is permitted, for example here, small simple sentences in the present tense... nevertheless, those sentences are too ambiguous, overly simple, and would rarely be spoken in actuality.  Maybe... "When I'm at work, she's asleep, and then vice versa" ,    "Usually, while I work she's sleeping."  If a sentence has too many possible meanings, that almost converts it into a "mistake", since the listener won't be able to interpret which meaning is right.
